# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" using flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am using `flask_api` to build a simple web application, however I get a `TypeError`.

Here is my code:

`user.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask.ext.api import FlaskAPI
from flask import request, url_for

class User_operations(object):

    def login_v(self):
        return 'hello'
```

`app.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask.ext.api import FlaskAPI
from user import User_operations

app = FlaskAPI(__name__)
bj = User_operations()

@app.route('/example/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def example():
    bj.login_v()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

This gives me the error:

```
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Comment: and tell us in which line the error occurs

Comment: on which file its wrong .I mean indentation

Comment: i think i am getting error on this line " bj.login_v()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view function `example` you are missing the `return statement`:

```
@app.route('/example/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def example():
  return bj.login_v()
```